# How to catch onmousewheel event on Opera?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, opera, mousewheel

I thought the following code targets both IE and Opera

```javascript
window.onload = function() {
    document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", function() {
        console.log("mousewheel detected");
    });
};
```

However, Opera (11.11) has no response at all.

I'v tried to Google this but didn't get any helpful info. Does Opera even support mousewheel event?

Combinations I'v tried...

`attachEvent`, `addEventListener` and `mousewheel`, `onmousewheel`, `DOMMouseScroll`

## update

ok, `mousewheel` event does get caught on Opera, the problem is that my Opera's console does not print anything out. `alert` works.

Comment: [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:DOM/element.addEventListener)?

Comment: @PeeHaa埽 isn't `addEventListener` for FF and Webkit?

Comment: Nope. `addEventListener` works on all decent browsers

Comment: @user1643156 Nope. `addEventListener` is [the standardized method](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/DOM-Level-3-Events/html/DOM3-Events.html#events-EventTarget-addEventListener) and [Opera has supported it for a while](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: well, how about a solution for older versions of Opera?

Comment: @user1643156 opera 7 is from 2003. Are you really supporting 10 year old browsers? That sucks ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle compatibility for all browsers and not switch to a solution that could break others. Simplest way of validating whether or not you can use a solution is "if".

In this case you can use 2 solutions. addEventListener & attachEvent.

```
var mousewheelevt=(/Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent))? "DOMMouseScroll" : "mousewheel" //FF doesn't recognize mousewheel as of FF3.x

if (document.attachEvent) //if IE (and Opera depending on user setting) {
    document.attachEvent("on"+mousewheelevt, function(e){alert('Mouse wheel movement detected!')})
else if (document.addEventListener) { //WC3 browsers
    document.addEventListener(mousewheelevt, function(e){alert('Mouse wheel movement detected!')}, false)
```

[Source](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml)

Comment: that is the code I'm using here. see my update, it's becasue Opera's console not printing anything out, my bad. thanks anyway.